# How would I prove that the $k$th derivative is $k+1$ for $y^{k}(x)=n^{k}y^{k}(nx)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know,

(1) $y'(x)=ny'(nx)$

(2) $y''(x) = n^{2}y''(nx)$

(3) $y'''(x)=n^{3}y'''(nx)$

$\implies$(k) $y^{k}(x)=n^{k}y^{k}(nx)$

Let us suppose $k$ holds and lets see if $m=k+1$ holds.

$\implies n^{k}y^{k}(x)=n^{k+1}y^{k+1}(x)$

Am I writing this correctly? Should it instead read.

$ n^{k}y^{t}(x)=n^{k+1}y^{t}(x)$, where $t$ is the $t$th derivative. This of course implies that $n^{k+1}=n^{k}$.

What would the next step be in the inductive proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you suppose that $y^{(k)}(x)=n^ky^{(k)}(nx)$, differentiating this equality gives you $$y^{(k+1)}(x)=n^k\times ny^{(k+1)}(nx)=n^{k+1}y^{(k+1)}(nx)$$

Comment: Ok, that was what I just thought to do but it seamed to simple. Thank you.